# What keeps installing wireless device drivers on my machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

My computer has become laggy. So I looked at task manager and something is using 100% CPU on one of the cores. It was the system interrupts. So I downloaded DPC latency checker and started disabling drivers. Nothing helped until I got to the network adpaters and I saw that there were over THIRTY (30) wireless device drivers sitting there. Realtek 8515 Extensible Wireless Device #2 through #32 of these things.

When I started disabling the lag stopped. The CPU usage stopped. Then windows just re-installed a whole take of them. So I disabled them again. When I rebooted the system would get stuck on the windows loading screen. So I reverted back and now I sit with the problem again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you remove them.  Please describe this process. A screenshot of might also be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound I went to the device manager and clicked uninstall one-by-one

Comment: A screenshot would be extremely handy.  Also providing the device driver details would be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to do a screenshot but I don't have enough rep. Sorry. I am not sure what details you are looking for. I gave the name. What else can I get you?

Comment: You can link to an image in a comment and people can add the screenshot inline to your question.  The best type of image includes the name of the file.  I can't help without the information I requested.

Comment: Do you actually have a Realtek 8515 Extensible Wireless Device on your computer? If so, you could try re-installing its device driver software (from the manufacturer, not one of those device driver download sites).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I do have a wireless network card. I did download the device drivers from the manufacturer. But maybe I should try to uninstall all the others and then re-install.